# Equal size for arbitrary levels of nested flex children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically, I want 1, 2 and 3 all be of the same width, and similarly if 4, 5, 6, etc. were added dynamically during runtime. Is it possible with pure CSS?

```js
x = 4;

$("button").on("click", () => {
  $(".active").removeClass("active").append(`
    <div class="flex active">
      <div>
        ${x++}
      </div>
    </div>
  `);
});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div>
      2
    </div>
    <div class="flex active">
      <div>
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>add</button>
```

Comment: just use css grid

Comment: @demkovych could you elaborate? I did try that without success, but I might be missing something

Comment: why you need nesting? can you explain your use case, maybe you are thinking the wrong way

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm making a vue component that displays a list. The catch is that if the list contains another list, it spawns another instance of the component itself to display that list. This could go on for arbitrary levels. Since each component can have only one root element I'm not sure if I can add it as a sibling to fit it like a regular flexbox child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:contents` to reduce the level on nesting:

```js
x = 4;

$("button").on("click", () => {
  $(".active").removeClass("active").append(`
    <div class="flex active">
      <div>
        ${x++}
      </div>
    </div>
  `);
});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex .flex {
  display:contents;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div>
      2
    </div>
    <div class="flex active">
      <div>
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>add</button>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I knew there was something out there that exposes the children directly to the parent's style, but I couldn't find it anywhere so I thought it was Deja Vu. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with css grid columns:

```css
#a {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

#a {
  background-color: #f77;
}

#b {
  background-color: #7f7;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column: 2 span;
}

#c {
  background-color: #77f;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="first">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <div>
      2
    </div>
    <div id="c">
      <div>
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question, but I need the `div`s to be the same width regardless of the levels of nesting. That is, if I dynamically add in more levels it would adjust to the same width as well. I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: I've added a button to add more nestings